# How to tell if a project uses Yarn

Tags: yarnpkg

How does one know if a project uses Yarn or NPM? Both contain a `package.json` file, although Yarn dependencies contain a file in the folder called `yarn.lock`.

Comment: If there is a `package-lock.json` file - the project uses npm, if there is a `yarn.lock` - yarn is used

Answer (score 17):

Both use `package.json` with the same JSON format, but NPM 5 generates a `package-lock.json` file, whereas Yarn generates a `yarn.lock` file.

Both will resolve to populating the `node_modules` folder with their own resolution algorithms.

Comment: Let's say you come across a project that has both `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` checked in, as I just did. (Or, equivalently, neither.) What do you do next?

Answer (score 9):

I created this shell alias to detect if a project uses `npm` or `yarn`.

```sh
alias npm_or_yarn='ls yarn.lock &> /dev/null && echo yarn || echo npm'
```

You can also create an alias to automatically run start using `npm` or `yarn`.

```sh
alias npm_or_yarn_start='$(npm_or_yarn) start'
```

Comment: can you explain more what this does?

Comment: @Later_72 if a `yarn.lock` file exists in the current directory it will echo `yarn` otherwise we redirect stderr that gets outputted if that file doesn't exist and echo `npm`

Answer (score 3):

Projects using npm will have a `package-lock.json` file while projects using yarn will have a `yarn.lock` file.

Comment: What if the project has both?

Comment: @stackunderflows
Then, it will have both (i guess )